# Leer múltiples archivos csv con FileReader en angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, csv

Estoy haciendo un programa con angular 2 y typescript que lee archivos csv del cliente y realiza cálculos y gráficos con los datos.
He conseguido leer un archivo correctamente, pero al ingresar el modo múltiple del input file y tratar de recoger dos archivos, me atasco y no encuentro ninguna solución.
Tengo en el html de la barra de navegación:

```
<li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><label for="file">Cargar CSV</label></li>
      <input type='file' name='userFile' id='file' (change)="onFileSelect($event.target)" style="display: none" multiple>
```

Luego tengo el componente principal que recibe los datos actualizados a traves de una variable estática:

```
export class GeochemComponent implements OnInit {

  static muestras:string[][]=[];
  static muestras2:string[][]=[];
}
```

Y los archivos se cargan y leen a través de un componente de barra de navegación, que es donde tengo el problema. Intento:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GeochemComponent, DibujaPuntos } from 
'../../geochem/geochem.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar-geochem',
  templateUrl: './navbar-geochem.component.html'
})
export class NavbarGeochemComponent implements OnInit {



onFileSelect(input: HTMLInputElement) {

var files = input.files;
var len = files.length;

for (var t=0;t<len;t++) {

  var fr = new FileReader();


    fr.onload = function(e) {
      var text = fr.result;
      var rows = text.split("\n");
      let arrayFilas:string[][]=[];
      //Incorporo los valores de cada celda a arrayFilas.
      for (var t=0;t<rows.length-1;t++) {
          if (rows[t].length!=0) {
              arrayFilas.push(rows[t].split(";"));
          }

      }

      if (t=0) {
        //Si es archivo 1
        GeochemComponent.muestras=arrayFilas.slice();
      } else if (t=1) {
        //Si es archivo 2
        GeochemComponent.muestras2=arrayFilas.slice();
      }

      };
      fr.readAsText(files[t],'ISO-8859-4');
    }
}



}
```

Y no se cargan dos arrays, uno por archivo, como esperaba al escribir el código. He buscado ejemplos y no encuentro ninguno que se adapte a lo que busco, y por mí mismo no consigo sacarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conseguí hacerlo generando el método que ya tenía para un archivo, e invocándolo tantas veces como archivos cargue:

```
leeArchivos(numarchivo:number,file:any) {
  var fr = new FileReader();
  var arrayFilas:string[][];
  fr.onload = function(e) {
    var text = fr.result;
    var rows = text.split("\n");
    arrayFilas=[];
    for (var t=0;t<rows.length-1;t++) {
      if (rows[t].length!=0) {
          arrayFilas.push(rows[t].split(";"));
      }
    }
    if(numarchivo==0) {
      GeochemComponent.muestras=arrayFilas.slice();
    } else if (numarchivo==1) {
      GeochemComponent.muestras2=arrayFilas.slice();
    }
  };
  fr.readAsText(file,'ISO-8859-4');
}
onFileSelect(input: HTMLInputElement) {
  var files = input.files;
  var len = files.length;
  for (var b=0;b<len;b++) {
    this.leeArchivos(b,files[b]);
  }
}
```